# Google Sheets script to sort table gives error "Cell reference out of range"

Tags: sorting, google-sheets

I'm relatively new to scripting in google sheets and am trying to write something that can be assigned to a button to sort a table by column 5 in that table. I am using the code below:

```
    function sort() {
       var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
       var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("items");
       var range = sheet.getRange("J2:O13");
       range.sort(5);
    }
```

However, when I assign it to a button and click the button, I get the error message "Cell reference out of range". This may be a stupid question but thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to sort on col 5 (E) but that is not in your range. The first column in your range is col 10 (J). If you want to sort on col O you'll need

```
range.sort(15)
```

Comment: OMG that's unintuitive.  Numerical values suggest relativity to the range selected, so why insist on numbers when you could just say range.sort("J")?   Conversely, if the column number is related to the entire spreadsheet, then how is it "out of range"?  This also makes reusing sorting functions require passing an offset.  This is all just wrong in so many ways!  Bah.

Comment: You are right @tudor, this is completely unintuitive. Just lost one hour searching why because I didn't have any error since my sheet was big...

Comment: I now use `range.getColumn()` to get the base column of my range, and then add an offset to get to the column within my range. And yes, this is incredibly non-intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with the App Script sort function. If you attempt to sort a range in place as you see here

```js
function autoSort() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("mySheet");
  
  const range = sheet.getRange("A1:Z");
  
  range.sort({
    column: 4,
    ascending: false
  );
}
```

You can expect to encounter the error **range.sort Error Exception: Cell reference out of range**.

This issue has been documented for years (source: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760889?pli=1)

To circumvent the issue, please use the standard Javascript sort function in combination with the ability to get and set the values of a range as seen below:

```js
function autoSort() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("mySheet");
  
  const range = sheet.getRange("A1:Z");
  
  range.setValues(range.getValues().sort((a, b) => b[3] - a[3]));
}
```

Here we use knowledge of the range values type as a 2D array representing the cells in the sheet and the standard Javascript sort function to sort in descending order on the 4th column as previously intended.

To learn more about writing effective sort functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort